# Send video as response to the user

Tags: java, jax-rs

I have a service that do the following things:

1) Get parameter from user (http get)

2) Return video file to user as response

3) My code is:

```
@GET
    @Path("/test")
    public Response test(@QueryParam("url") final String videoUrl) {
        final CrawlerResult result = this.crawlerService.crawl(videoUrl);
        if (result.isSuccess()) {
            final StreamingOutput fileStream = this.crawlerService.videoAsStream(result.getResult());
            return Response.ok(fileStream, MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
                           .header("content-disposition", "attachment; filename = movie.mp4")
                           .build();
        } else {
            return Response.status(Response.Status.NOT_ACCEPTABLE)
                    .entity(result)
                    .build();
        }
    }
```

And `CrawlerService`:

```
@Override
    public StreamingOutput videoAsStream(final String videoUrl) {
        try {
            final URL url = new URL(videoUrl);
            return output -> {
                output.write(IOUtils.toByteArray(url));
                output.flush();
            };
        } catch (final MalformedURLException e) {
            log.error("Url exception for url {}",videoUrl);
            throw new UncheckedIOException(e);
        }
    }
```

As you see I take a url , make `URL` object then write URL to `StreamingOutput` using `IOUTILS`

This work fine for short videos, but when video is too long , user wait for response about 5 minutes.

Is it any possible way to rewrite my logic?

Comment: You are already streaming so that should be fine. What are you doing here `final CrawlerResult result = this.crawlerService.crawl(videoUrl);`?

Comment: I validate given url

Comment: @SMA the problem with this line of code
`output.write(IOUtils.toByteArray(url));`

It executing too long for long movies

Comment: That's where you are streaming bytes back to client? It would depend as well on how quickly clients take that streamed data

Comment: @SMA `return Response.ok(fileStream, MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)`

Comment: If you are using `output.write(IOUtils.toByteArray(url));`, then you are not streaming. You are first converting all data to a byte array, and then sending that in one go to the recipient. Stop doing that.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I found a solution
I replace

```
output.write(IOUtils.toByteArray(url));
                output.flush();
```

To

```
return output -> {
                IOUtils.copy(url.openConnection().getInputStream(),output);
                output.flush();
                output.close();
            };
```